# Sql query result duplicate

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Hi all first I have table t1 like this

```
ID  cid     enter     sort
===================
1             20
2      1                5 
3.     1.               6
4             10    
5      4                 2
6.             30
```

I need to get result like this

```
ID  enter    sort     stock
===============================
1    20       11        9
4    10        2          8
6.    30.      0.        30
```

What means
Get all id where cid is null take the enter number 
Then get all cid where cid =id take sum of sort number
Then finally stock = enter - sort

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P7mG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0modO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9oI0.png)

like mu db the result must be like this

```
ID  enter    sort     stock
===============================
18    1P       6        4
```

my query

```
 SELECT        p_stock.id, p_stock.code, p_stock.quant_entr, SUM(p_stock_1.quant_sort) AS Expr1
FROM            (p_stock INNER JOIN
                         p_stock p_stock_1 ON p_stock.id = p_stock_1.cid)
HAVING        (p_stock.id = 18) AND (p_stock.code = 27)
```

Thank you for help

Comment: How are your rows related?  Are you assuming that the matching row is the one with the next higher id?

Comment: Would it be possible to add an example table showing where the stock column comes from? Generally, you have to join the two tables together, one of your tables will have a column which has a pointer (called a foreign key) which should match the primary key of the other table.

Comment: i add some photos for mor understand

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.enter, t2.sort, (t1.enter - t2.sort) as stock
from t as t1 join
     t as t2
     on t2.id = t1.id + 1
where t1.id in (1, 3)   -- or perhaps all odd numbers
```